# Motor noise problem

Tags: sensor, dc-motor, raspberry-pi, noise, electromagnetism

I am building a POV display, where all modules work with 5V (Raspberry Pi / apa102 LED strip / motor).

First I built an ESC module using a universal PCB which uses 5V from the power supply and a PWM signal from the Raspberry.

There is also a speed sensor (encoder) circuit that uses a Schmitt-trigger IC (assembled on a breadboard) to adapt the signal to the Raspberry.

At this stage everything was good and there was no problem with the sensor and the Raspberry GUI was printing speed values without any problem. But when I assembled everything on the PCB, the speed values glitched sometimes and gave wrong measurements.

**I noticed also that when I shut the motor down the measurement became correct (slow-down speed was right and smooth). It appeared that the motor is the cause of this. Maybe it was making noise.** All this happened when I was testing at home. But the big surprise is that this does not happen at my university where the values are correct anyway. Even the oscilloscope shows very little noise.

**My question is: why didn't my PCB work properly at my house but works alright at my University?**

Did I make a mistake by assembling everything on one PCB? Especially the ESC?

The following picture is my PCB:

[image]

The following is the electronic schematic of the ESC section and sensing section:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your standard lack of decoupling, layout or measurement setup issue. Please show how you measure your signal.

Comment: I don't think so i am using decoupling capacitors probably every were also  there is pull up resistors... Okey i will post the sensing part as soon as possible

Comment: There's a good chance that it's a ground loop or some other wiring issue.  Is the motor being powered off of the same 5V regulated supply that's running your computer?  Is the ground wire from the ESC sharing the ground wire with other parts of the circuit?  Is your encoder ground common with the motor drive wires?  Are your encoder wires run adjacent to your motor drive wires with no shielding?

Comment: Decoupling is key. Is your motor brushed? If yes, do you have a flyback diode across it?

Comment: @winny yes my motor is brushed and it is DC .. yes i have flyback diode...

Comment: @TimWescott the raspberry pi and the motor are using the same power supply (5 V - 20 A)... All components are sharing the same GND including encoder   ... The motor takes GND through the MOSFET drain ... Yes they are adjacent without shielding...Note : ( motor PWM signal is 20 kHz)

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors? Hoe does the 5V1 and 5V look under load form the motor on your oscilloscope?

Comment: @TimWescott makes good points about wiring. You might also try *twisting together* the two wires to each motor, in an effort to reduce electromagnetic radiation. Speed-sensor wires might be twisted together too. A small-value capacitor might be added across the motor in an effort to reduce brush noise.

Comment: @winny look at the schematics C4 and C5 ...5V1 looks good very little noise and disappear at high speed ... For 5v which comes from the raspberry pi i don't know (i didn't test)...

Comment: @glen_geek i did that indeed ... At my home the measurement was noisy but when i add motor capacitor things seems better but not enough .... When i went to my university the measurement became very smooth and precise  even when i removed motor capacitor.. why this happened ? I dont know !!

Comment: Are you using a different power supply at home than at your university?  How are your encoders connected to power, the Pi, and ground?

Comment: @TimWescott no it is the same ,it is my own power supply, it gives (5V -20A) you can see it up-left in picture ...the only thing i change it is that at my home i access my raspberry from my PC through WIFI network  (remote control) , while at my university i used monitor connected to raspberry pi and mouse/keyboard .....my encoder  is connected to (5V - GND- gpio20) all from raspberry pi ...  All components have common GND. The raspberry pi uses the same power supply  that the PCB uses ... It takes power from USB integrated on PCB (see the picture) I

Comment: By common ground do you mean everything goes to the PCB net called "GND", but is physically attached any which where on the board, or is there **one spot** on the board where **separate** ground wires from motor, encoder, and Pi converge?

Comment: The second one is correct

Answer (score 1):

The motor and logic should have own power supply, separate the voltage for logic with diode and place a low-pass after it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE7M7R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you mean that  the logic wire goes to raspberry pi power input or what ? If that what you mean ... How that is possible if the raspberry pi uses 2.5 A and 5.25 V exactly .... The diode will drop voltage and the resistor must above 12.5 W ...

Comment: R1 is probably not necessary, although D2 probably needs to be capable of more current (I'd use a Schottkey rated for 2.5A).  Check your Raspberry Pi specs, you can probably get away with giving it slightly less than 5V.

Comment: @TimWescott no if you try just 5V , the red LED will start blinking to indicate that the power supply is less then recommended which is 5.25 V (this what happen to me)